# Alternatives to VSCode's extension "Remote - Containers"

Tags: docker

I'm a bit tired of developing with CPU 100% all the time, and having to turn off my computer after I'm done (so that Docker does not randomly start a Node process that uses 100% CPU).

Is there an alternative to this extension that allows me to edit code inside a Docker container?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, the vanilla SSH tool is as good as connecting directly to the Docker container.

File searching speeds are also great.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).